# BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffffffffff

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, ioctl, userspace

I have an ioctl handler in my kernel driver and that has read and write ioctls. I also have a userspace application which uses this IOCTL to write/read data.

When I use this ioctl in my userspace application, it's causing a kernel OOPS with `"BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffffffffff"`

Userspace snippet:

```
typedef struct abc_T {
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t addr;
    uint8_t data[64];
} abc_T;

// Read
int abc_read(uint8_t addr, uint8_t size, uint8_t * data) {
     abc_T abc = {};
     int fd;
     int retval = 0;
     abc.size = size;
     abc.addr = addr;
     fd = open("/dev/"ABC_DEV, O_RDWR);

     if (fd >=0) {
       retval = ioctl(fd, READ_ABC, &abc);
       if (retval == 0)
           memcpy(data, abc.data, size);
     }
     close(fd);
     return retval;
}

// Write
int abc_write(uint8_t addr, uint8_t size, uint8_t * data) {
     abc_T abc = {};
     int fd;
     int retval = 0;
     abc.size = size;
     abc.addr = addr;
     memcpy(abc.data, data, size);
     fd = open("/dev/"ABC_DEV, O_RDWR);

     if (fd >=0) {
       retval = ioctl(fd, WRITE_ABC, &abc);
     }
     close(fd);
     return retval;
}
```

Kernel:

```
static int ABC_ioctl(struct file * file, uint cmd, ulong arg)
{
ABC_T abc;
int retval;

if (copy_from_user(&abc, (void *)arg,
                        sizeof(ABC_T)) != 0) {
    return -EFAULT;
}

switch(cmd) {
    case READ_ABC:
    retval = read_func(&abc);
    if (retval == 0) {
        if (copy_to_user((void *)arg, &abc,
                     sizeof(ABC_T)) != 0) {
                retval = -EFAULT;
        } else {
            retval = 0;
        }
    }
    break;
case WRITE_ABC:
    ret_val = write_func(&abc);
    break;
return retval;
}
```

```
Error: 
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffffffffff
IP: [<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xfffffffffffffffe
PGD 1e0f067 PUD 1e11067 PMD 0 
Oops: 0010 [#1] PREEMPT SMP 
...
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff8117a8b8>] ? vfs_write+0x198/0x1b0
 [<ffffffff8118ccc0>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x80/0x90
 [<ffffffff8117b139>] ? SyS_write+0x49/0xa0
 [<ffffffff819af419>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Code:  Bad RIP value.
RIP  [<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xfffffffffffffffe
...
```

Not sure what is wrong in this.
Can someone please help?

Update: with the array size of 32 in abc_T, I do not see the problem. But when I change the array size to 64, I see the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Update 2: with array size of 64 in abc_T, if read/write `size` is <= 32, there is no problem, only when the `size` to be read/written is greater than 32, crash is seen.

Comment: Can you show how you register the chardev? (especially including the structures). It very much looks like the write function pointer isn't properly initialized.

Comment: ```static struct file_operations abc_fops = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = ABC_ioctl,
    .open           = abc_open,
    .release        = abc_release,
};```

Comment: ```        if (alloc_chrdev_region(&abc_dev, 0, 1, ABC_DEV) < 0) {
                return -1;
        }

        if (device_create(dev_class, NULL, abc_dev, NULL, ABC_DEV) == NULL) {
                unregister_chrdev_region(abc_dev, 1);
                return -1;
        }

        cdev_init(&abc_cdev, &abc_fops);
        if (cdev_add(&abc_cdev, abc_dev, 1) == -1) {
                device_destroy(dev_class, abc_dev);
                unregister_chrdev_region(abc_dev, 1);
                return -1;
        }
```

Comment: Can you determine, which call in your userspace-client triggers the fault? Don't assume, make sure

Comment: after some debugging, I've found out that if I have the array size of `data` in `abc_T` as 32, it doesn't crash, while changing it to 64 makes it crash. But I need it to be more than 32 :(

Comment: @Ctx is there any limit on the array size that can be sent from userspace to kernel using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be sure this is your problem but you have some problems in your code

In

```
int abc_read(uint8_t addr, uint8_t size, uint8_t * data) {
     abc_T abc = {};
     int fd, retval;
     abc.size = size;
     abc.addr = addr;
     fd = open("/dev/"ABC_DEV, O_RDWR);

     if (fd >=0) {
     retval = ioctl(fd, READ_ABC, &abc);
     if (retval == 0)
         memcpy(data, abc.data, size);

     }
return retval;
}
```

if *open* fails *retval* is never set but you return it, the behavior is unspecified in `ABC_ioctl` because you use the return value

We do not see the end of `abc_write`, do you return a value if *open* fails ?

P.S. I first supposed you do the *memcpy* even the open fails, please take care with the indent (I edited your question to change it)

---

May be look at [How to use ioctl to read and write to a chardev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309661/how-to-use-ioctl-to-read-and-write-to-a-chardev)

Comment: okay, that was a mistake. I'm initializing the retval to 0 initially. Will edit that part.

Comment: @oak1208 you mean your real code initializes it with 0, so the code you give us is not the real one ?

Comment: it is the real one. I just missed that while typing the question :)

Comment: @oak1208 ok, so the init was missing. I edited my question, do you return a value in `abc_write` if _open_ fails ?

Comment: i don't think that's the problem, since when i printed the value of `fd` it's always >0.

Comment: I know the return shouldn't be `0` if open fails, I will change that, but `fd` is always > 0.

Comment: `READ_ABC` is probably a macro, which one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189459/discussion-between-oak1208-and-bruno).

Answer (score 0):

Given these updates:

> Update: with the array size of 32 in abc_T, I do not see the problem.
>   But when I change the array size to 64, I see the issue. Any help
>   would be appreciated.
>
> Update 2: with array size of 64 in abc_T, if read/write size is <= 32,
>   there is no problem, only when the size to be read/written is greater
>   than 32, crash is seen.

You are likely overrunning the space allocated for the kernel call stack.

Code like this

```
 abc_T abc = {};
```

allocates an `abc_T` object on the call stack, which is *extremely* limited inside the kernel.  You should probably use [`kmalloc()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html):

```
abc_T *abc = kmalloc( sizeof( *abc ), GFP_KERNEL );
```

You'd need to check the result, and free any memory allocated by using [`kfree()`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kfree.html):

```
kfree( abc );
```